# Typo3 6.2.5 Quixplorer alternatives?

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I just did a fresh Typo3 6.2.5 Install and wanted to use some kind of file editor which is able to edit .htaccess in Typo3 root. The standard BE file list doesn't list any file above fileadmin.

In the past T3Quixplorer was the way to go for me, but it doesn't seem to be developed any further. I found the kmcs_fileedit extension but that doesn't allow me to edit .htaccess.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should really (really really) consider to set up a local development system and an automated deployment process. Then you can edit the .htaccess in whatever IDE or editor you like. This also improves security, for example you generally don't want the webserver or PHP-user to be able to modify its configuration (.htaccess). But when using something like T3Quixplorer, at least the PHP user must have writing-rights for the .htaccess.

Comment: Gimme your email and i will send you a working version of quixplorer with TYPO3 6.2

Comment: Dont. Use. Quixplorer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to **kmcs_fileedit** configuration (field `Editable file extensions`) in **Extension Manager**:

`|\.htaccess$`

Answer (score 0):

1. There is an early extbase-version available on Github:

   [Quixplorer: Extbase-Version](https://github.com/madsbrunn/t3quixplorer/tree/extbaseVersion).

   This version is working on Typo3 6.2, but it might not include every feature.

---

2. You can also try to get the [original version](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/t3quixplorer) running on Typo3 6.2 by modifying the `t3quixplorer/mod1/index.php` file
   of the extension.

   Comment out lines **55** and **57** of the file:

   `...
   /*require ($BACK_PATH.'template.php');*/
   $LANG->includeLLFile('EXT:t3quixplorer/mod1/locallang.xml');
   /*require_once (PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_scbase.php');*/
   ...`

   Then the extension should be working again on typo3 6.2

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution without any additional extension usage is to create a new **File Storage** record with a *Base path* set to `/` or `typo3conf/ext/`.

However the drawback is that you must add the file extensions also to `[SYS][textfile_ext]`in the Install Tool.